# Error: 9 while fitting sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB()

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, feature-extraction, text-classification, countvectorizer

While fitting Multinomial Naive Bayes Classifier with TfidfCountvectorizer, I am getting killed: 9 error

```
def classify(vector, df):
    clf = MultinomialNB()
    model = clf.fit(vector, df.iloc[0:, 1].values)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    train, test = gen_train_test(pd.read_csv('Data/datalabel.csv'))
    vector = joblib.load('Data/tf.pkl')
    classify(vector, train, name='mnb')
    print('Program executed!')
```

Here, the train is of size 409MB, and the vector is of size 20.3GB.

I am using a MacBook Pro-13 2017, 8GB RAM, 256 GB SSD.

Comment: How did you manage to load `vector is of size 20.3GB` into `8GB RAM`?

Comment: Are you getting any stack trace of error? How are you calling this script? In terminal, in an IDE?

Comment: MaxU- I used the joblib package to dump and load vectorizer instead of pickle. Joblib compresses the data.

Comment: Vivek Kumar- It is only showing Error: 9. It's related to the memory. I am calling the script by using the python3 command on PyCharm.

Comment: It compresses the data while saving to disc, when loading in memory it will decompress it all to original form. How did you manage to save it in the first place?

Comment: Swap space managed this as I have a fast SSD.

Answer (score 0):

This simple modification in code solved the issue

```
vector = joblib.load(open('Data/tf.pkl', 'rb'))
```